# How to Figure out the MAX and MIN of Groups that have been Added together

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How do would you get the MAX value of a column that has been grouped and add together by _id.

So something like this:

[image]

I then want to display the MAX value of the four groups, as well as the MIN value of the four groups.

Something like this Scratch High = 702 / Scratch Low = 325

Is this possible with the built in Math functions of SQLite or would I need to write specific code to accomplish this?  The actual number of groups will be more than 4, it will depend on how often the bowler actually bowls a series.

I haven't written any code for this as of yet, I am attempting to figure out if this is even possible before attempting to do so.  Any suggestions would be welcome.
My attempt to integrate into my Project:

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public static final String DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE = "max_score";
    public static final String DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE = "min_score";

    public Cursor getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            String tmptbl = "summed_scores";
            String tmptblcol = "sum_score";

            String crttmptbl = "CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tmptbl + "(" +
                    tmptblcol + " INTEGER" +
                    ")";
            String empttmptbl = "DELETE FROM " + tmptbl;

            db.execSQL(crttmptbl);
            db.execSQL(empttmptbl);
            String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(score) AS " + tmptblcol};
            Cursor csr = db.query(Game.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID,null,null);
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(tmptblcol,csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(tmptblcol)));
                db.insert(tmptbl,null,cv);
            }
            csr.close();

            columns = new String[]{"max(" +
                    tmptblcol +
                    ") AS " + DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE,
                    "min(" +
                            tmptblcol +
                            ") AS " + DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE};
            return csr = db.query(tmptbl,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        }

        public MaxMin getMaxAndminScoresAll() {
            MaxMin rv = new MaxMin(0,0);
            Cursor csr = getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid();
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                rv.setMin(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE)));
                rv.setMax(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE)));
            }
            csr.close();
            return rv;
        }
```

BowlerProfileViewActivity.java

```
public class BowlerProfileViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bowler bowler;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String PREF_BLUE_THEME = "blue_theme";
    private static final String PREF_GREEN_THEME = "green_theme";
    private static final String PREF_ORANGE_THEME = "purple_theme";
    private static final String PREF_RED_THEME = "red_theme";
    private static final String PREF_YELLOW_THEME = "yellow_theme";

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        //mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(db.getAllLeagues());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Use Chosen Theme
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean useBlueTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_BLUE_THEME, false);
        if (useBlueTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useGreenTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_GREEN_THEME, false);
        if (useGreenTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useOrangeTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_ORANGE_THEME, false);
        if (useOrangeTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Orange_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useRedTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_RED_THEME, false);
        if (useRedTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red_NoActionBar);
        }
        boolean useYellowTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_YELLOW_THEME, false);
        if (useYellowTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow_NoActionBar);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowler_profile_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Boolean shouldUpdate = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("shouldUpdate");
        String savedLeagueId = intent.getStringExtra("leagueId");
        String savedBowlerId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("bowlerId",2));
        int bowlerId = Integer.valueOf(savedBowlerId);

        getBowlerProfile(savedLeagueId, bowlerId);

        // Get The min and max score
        MaxMin bowlerMaxMin =  db.getMaxAndminScoresAll();
        Log.d("SCORES",
                "\n\tMaximum Score is " + String.valueOf(bowlerMaxMin.getMax()) +
                        "\n\tMinimum Score is " + String.valueOf(bowlerMaxMin.getMin()));

    }

    public void getBowlerProfile(String savedLeagueId, int savedBowlerId) {

        String bn, ba, bh;

        SQLiteOpenHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor viewBowlerProfile = db.query( Bowler.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Bowler.COLUMN_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE, Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP, Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Bowler.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(savedBowlerId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (viewBowlerProfile.moveToFirst()) {

            //Prepare League Object
            bowler = new Bowler(
                    viewBowlerProfile.getInt(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)),
                    viewBowlerProfile.getString(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                    bn = viewBowlerProfile.getString(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)),
                    ba = viewBowlerProfile.getString(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE)),
                    bh = viewBowlerProfile.getString(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP)),
                    viewBowlerProfile.getString(viewBowlerProfile.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

            final TextView bowlerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerName);
            final TextView bowlerAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerAverageValue);
            final TextView bowlerHandicap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerHandicapValue);

            bowlerName.setText(String.valueOf(bn));
            bowlerAverage.setText(String.valueOf(ba));
            bowlerHandicap.setText(String.valueOf(bh));

            //Close Database Connection
            viewBowlerProfile.close();
        }

        //View League Profile Cancel Button
        final Button cancel_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("SAVEDLEAGUEID_VAL", ">>" + String.valueOf(savedLeagueId) + "<<");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", savedLeagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", savedLeagueId);
                Log.d("LEAGUEID VALUE","value of leagueId = " + String.valueOf(savedLeagueId));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);*/
            }

        });

        //Edit League Profile Cancel Button
        final Button edit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
        edit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int bowlerId = bowler.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerProfileEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bowlerId", bowlerId);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", savedLeagueId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'ca.rvogl.tpbcui.utils.MaxMin ca.rvogl.tpbcui.database.DatabaseHelper.getMaxAndminScoresAll()' on a null object reference
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.BowlerProfileViewActivity.onCreate(BowlerProfileViewActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
```

Attempting to group by bowlerId and seriesId

```
public Cursor getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid(String bowlerId) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String tmptbl = "summed_scores";
    String tmptblcol = "sum_score";
    String tmpBowlerIdCol = "bowler_id";
    String tmpSeriesIdCol = "series_id";

    String crttmptbl = "CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tmptbl + "(" +
            tmptblcol + " INTEGER," + 
            tmpBowlerIdCol + " TEXT," + 
            tmpSeriesIdCol + " TEXT)";
    String empttmptbl = "DELETE FROM " + tmptbl;

    db.execSQL(crttmptbl);
    db.execSQL(empttmptbl);
    String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(score) AS "};
    Cursor csr = db.query(Game.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'", Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID,null,null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(tmptblcol,csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(tmptblcol)));
        cv.put(tmpBowlerIdCol,csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(tmpBowlerIdCol)));
        cv.put(tmpSeriesIdCol,csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(tmpSeriesIdCol)));
        db.insert(tmptbl,null,cv);
    }
    csr.close();

    columns = new String[]{"max(" +
            tmptblcol +
            ") AS " + DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE,
            "min(" +
                    tmptblcol +
                    ") AS " + DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE};
    return csr = db.query(tmptbl,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public MaxMin getMaxAndminScoresAll(String bowlerId) {
    MaxMin rv = new MaxMin(0,0);
    Cursor csr = getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid(bowlerId);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv.setMin(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE)));
        rv.setMax(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE)));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure which part of this problem is that you have difficulty with. But in general, it depends on what objects you use to store the content of the table. Assuming that you have one collection (array, list, queue, etc) for each group, you may want to iterate over each collection (i.e., groups) and find the max value. Then, store the values as well as the group ids somewhere (perhaps in a `map`). Finally, find the largest value and the corresponding group id.

Comment: I am kind of new to this.  What do mean by map?

Comment: `map` is a family of data structures in Java that let you keep pairs of values. In your case pairs like <id, max>. To see some examples see this: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this (assuming the table is named **myscores** and the columns are **_id** and **score**) using :-

```
WITH cte1 AS 
    (
        sum(score) AS sum_score
        FROM myscores
        GROUP BY _id
    )
SELECT max(sum_score) AS min_score, min(sum_score) FROM cte1;
```

Using this would result in the following :-

[image]

- **Notes**
- **`AS`** is used to rename the output columns

  - without renaming the columns they would be named **max(sum_score)** and **min(sum_score)** respectively.
    [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Aggregate Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)

This utilises the SQLite aggregate functions **max** and **min** and the GROUP BY clause to aggregate the columns according to the _id column.

This also utilises a Common Table Expression (an intermediate/temporary table).
[SQL As Understood By SQLite - WITH clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

---

## Incorporating into an Android App (see note at end)

The following is an example App demonstrates how this can be incorporated fro Android :-

First a simple class for the Minimum and maximum vales (as used in the alternative getMaxAndMinScores method)

### MaxMin.java (optional)

```
public class MaxMin {

    private int min;
    private int max;

    public MaxMin(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

### DBHelper.java

The subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper (just the one table name myscores)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_SCORE = "myscores";
    public static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;

    public static final String DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE = "max_score";
    public static final String DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE = "min_score";

    private static final String crt_myscores_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_SCORE + "(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER," +
            COL_SCORE + " INTEGER" +
            ")";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_myscores_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addScore(long id, int score) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ID,id);
        cv.put(COL_SCORE,score);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TB_SCORE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getMaxMinScores() {
        String sum_score = "sum_score";
        String cte1 = "cte1";
        String rawqry = " WITH " + cte1 +
                " AS " +
                "(" +
                "SELECT sum(" +
                COL_SCORE +
                ") AS " + sum_score +
                " FROM " + TB_SCORE + " GROUP BY " + COL_ID +
                ") " +
                "SELECT " +
                " max(" +
                sum_score +
                ") AS " + DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE +
                "," +
                " min(" +
                sum_score +
                ") AS " + DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE +
                " FROM " + cte1 + ";";
        return this.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(rawqry,null);
    }

    public MaxMin getMaxAndMinScores() {
        MaxMin rv = new MaxMin(0,0);
        Cursor csr = getMaxMinScores();
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv.setMin(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE)));
            rv.setMax(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

The activity that a) adds some rows and then b) gets the maximum and minimum scores (twice using alternative methods) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        // Add Some scores
        mDBHlpr.addScore(1,112);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(1,123);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(1,144);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(2,212);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(2,190);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(2,300);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(3,234);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(3,134);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(3,122);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(4,100);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(4,111);
        mDBHlpr.addScore(4,114);

        // Get The min and max scores example 1
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getMaxMinScores();
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            int max_score = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE));
            int min_score = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE));
            Log.d("SCORES",
                    "\n\tMaximum Score is " + String.valueOf(max_score) +
                            "\n\tMinimum Score is " + String.valueOf(min_score)
            );
        }

        //Alternative utilising the MaxMin object
        MaxMin mymaxmin =  mDBHlpr.getMaxAndMinScores();
        Log.d("SCORES",
                "\n\tMaximum Score is " + String.valueOf(mymaxmin.getMax()) +
                        "\n\tMinimum Score is " + String.valueOf(mymaxmin.getMin())
        );
    }
}
```

#### IMPORTANT

> **The `WITH` clause was introduced in SQL 3.8.3, some older versions of Android (below lollipop (but can be device independent)) will not
>   support the `WITH` clause.**

The following methods, as equivalents of `getMaxMinScores` and `getMaxAndMinScores` could be used for any Android version :-

```
public Cursor getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String tmptbl = "summed_scores";
    String tmptblcol = "sum_score";

    String crttmptbl = "CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tmptbl + "(" +
            tmptblcol + " INTEGER" +
            ")";
    String empttmptbl = "DELETE FROM " + tmptbl;

    db.execSQL(crttmptbl);
    db.execSQL(empttmptbl);
    String[] columns = new String[]{"sum(score) AS " + tmptblcol};
    Cursor csr = db.query(TB_SCORE,columns,null,null,COL_ID,null,null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(tmptblcol,csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(tmptblcol)));
        db.insert(tmptbl,null,cv);
    }
    csr.close();

    columns = new String[]{"max(" +
            tmptblcol +
            ") AS " + DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE,
            "min(" +
                    tmptblcol +
                    ") AS " + DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE};
    return csr = db.query(tmptbl,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public MaxMin getMaxAndminScoresAllAndroid() {
    MaxMin rv = new MaxMin(0,0);
    Cursor csr = getMaxMinScoresAllAndroid();
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv.setMin(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOl_MINSCORE)));
        rv.setMax(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DERIVEDCOL_MAXSCORE)));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- These utilise an intermediate temporary table so bypass the restriction of using **`WITH`**

Comment: thanks for the awesome explanation.  I have been trying to merge what you provided below into my project.  I have posted my attempt above.  As you can see I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'ca.rvogl.tpbcui.utils.MaxMin ca.rvogl.tpbcui.database.DatabaseHelper.getMaxAndMinScores()' on a null object reference` on this line `MaxMin mymaxmin =  db.getMaxAndMinScores();` am I missing something?

Comment: At a guess, your **DatabaseHelper** class is not a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper and thus **this.getWritableDatabase** is null. In the example code in **DBHelper.java** the line `public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`, is making the DBHelper class a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper. Include the methods, **getMaxAndMinScores** and **getMaxMinScores** into your Database Helper class which is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, then **this** will resolve to be be an SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: The DatabaseHelper is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper the class starts like this `public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`  and I did place the two methods inside of DatabaseHelper.  I could post the entire DatabaseHelper, however it is very lengthy.

Comment: @RobertVogl I believe the issue is that you instantiating the **db** (instance of DatabaseHelper). you only do this in the `onResume` method. As such db will be null within the `onCreate` method. There would be no need to instantiate it in the `onResume` method as **db** is a class variable. So move the line `db = new DatabaseHelper(this);` from the `onResume` method to the `onCreate` method in **BowlerProfileViewActivity.java**.

Comment: sorry for the delay in getting back to you on this.  Been out of town for a few days.  I was successful in running your example above in a separate project.  Will attempt to integrate into main project at a later date, just working through some other issues at the moment.

Comment: I am back to trying to get this integrated into my App.  I am trying to use the method you provided for all Android versions.  Like I mentioned above I was able to get this to work in its own project, but when I try to bring into my App it is telling me I have null pointer on line 79, which is `MaxMin bowlerMaxMin =  db.getMaxAndminScoresAll();`  any ideas what I am doing wrong from the code I posted above?

Comment: Odds on you are again not instantiating **db** before invoking `MaxMin bowlerMaxMin = db.getMaxAndminScoresAll();`

Comment: yes you where correct,  I forgot that you had mentioned this before. As you mentioned above moving the db = new DatabaseHelper(this); out of the resume() corrected this issue.  Thank you once again.

Comment: this work perfectly, but as I was going through the different bowlers in a league I noticed that they all have the same values.  I modified the code to accept the input of a bowlerId to group on.  However it had no impact on the results.  I am sure it has something to do with the temp table.  How do I transfer the seriesId and the bowlerId to it, or is this even necessary. I posted my modified code above.